# VBA to halve values in specific cells (if the value in an adjacent cell is above a certain threshold)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate a process whereby we half a reduction is the item being sold has more than 10 watchers (clothing e-commerce).

I have two columns, (A & B), both are which are populated with values. A contains reductions we're making, whereas B contains the number of watchers. I want to write a sub that halves the reduction if the no. of watchers is above 10.

This is the code I've come up with but I can only seem to do it line by line... Please could someone help me do it for the whole data set (by making it dynamic/ by looping it)

```
Sub Half()
 Dim Data As Range
 Dim cell As Range
 Set Data = Range("A1")
 For Each cell In Data
  If cell.Value > 3 Then
   Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value / 2
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a remark: If you overwrite the values in column A by calling your routine, you will loose the original value. You will not be able to see if the routine was already executed. If you call the routine a second time, the cells will contain only 1/4 of the original value. Maybe it's better to hold the original value in col A and introduce a helper column with the calculated values. Additionally, your task can easily be done using a formula, no VBA needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we start with:

[image]

running:

```
Sub half()
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, A As Range
    Set rng = Range("B1:B10")
    For Each cell In rng
        Set A = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        If cell.Value > 10 Then A.Value = A.Value / 2
    Next cell
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

*(Adjust the limits to match your data)*

**EDIT#1:**

This will auto-select the bottom of the data:

```
Sub half()
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, A As Range, LastRow As Long
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    
    For Each cell In rng
        Set A = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        If cell.Value > 10 Then A.Value = A.Value / 2
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there any way to do this if the range is not fixed (could be more or less than 10 rows)? I've tried to incorporate LastRow =
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row into it (declaring x as a long and then  specifying for x = 2 to LastRow) but it doesnt work.

Comment: @Lysander2001  Se my **EDIT#1**